# Get an int from an array of chars

Tags: c, casting, alignment

I have an array of 50 `char`s:

```
char arr[50];
```

I'm told that in `arr[1]` till `arr[4]`, there is an `int` I need to get.

I did :

```
int *p = (int *)(arr+1);

return *p;
```

I was told it's a mistake. Why?

Comment: Because it violates the [strict aliasing rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Comment: The question's underspecified here.  Certainly what H2CO3 says is true, but your instructor may have meant four text digits, or may have been talking about endianness in class.  edit: and I see you put the alignment tag yourself, is there a reason you don't say why that's not a good enough answer here?

Answer (score 0):

On my system, `sizeof(char)=1`, `sizeof(int)=4`.

The root of the issue is that you are casting to a pointer to int `(int *)`, which is masking the true alignment of the underlying type `char`. Assuming a 4-byte int, the compiler tries to access 4 bytes instead of 1.

Given:

```
char arr[] = "ABCDEFGHI";
```

Then your code yields:

```
int *p = (int *)(arr+1); /* *p = 1162101570, interpreting "BCDE" as int */
```

In order to take advantage of C's automatic type conversion, you need something more like this:

```
int p = (int)(*(arr+1)); /* p = 66, the ASCII code for 'B' */
```

or, less obscure, and more technically correct based on your original declaration of `arr`,

```
int p = (int)arr[1]; /* p = 66 */
```

but really, this is all you need:

```
int p = arr[1]; /* p = 66 */
```